# jersey Maven project POM.XML 1st line error

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, jersey

I have implemented a hospital management system with REST api.when my individual part is running without any error.but we integrated this project using GitHub, then it gives an error in pom.xml 1st line.this is error line in the code.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

this is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Hospital</groupId>
  <artifactId>Hospital</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.48</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

this is my error

```
Apr 17, 2020 5:53:40 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class homePage.service.HomePageService
  class doctors.service.DoctorService
  class hospital.service.HospitalService
  class user.service.UserLoginService
  class user.service.UserRegisterService
  class payment.service.PaymentService
Apr 17, 2020 5:53:40 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Apr 17, 2020 5:53:41 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.4 05/24/2017 03:46 PM'
Apr 17, 2020 5:53:43 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String hospital.service.HospitalService.ReadHospitals(), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String hospital.service.HospitalService.insertHoapitalDet(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String hospital.service.HospitalService.deleteHospitalDet(java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String hospital.service.HospitalService.updateHospitalDet(java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String doctors.service.DoctorService.updateDoctor(java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String doctors.service.DoctorService.insertDoctor(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String doctors.service.DoctorService.deleteDoctor(java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String doctors.service.DoctorService.readDoctors(), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String user.service.UserRegisterService.insertUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,int), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String user.service.UserLoginService.validateLogin(java.lang.String,java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String user.service.UserLoginService.readUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String user.service.UserLoginService.updateUser(java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String user.service.UserLoginService.deleteUser(java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public java.lang.String payment.service.PaymentService.validatePayment(java.lang.String,java.lang.String), with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
Apr 17, 2020 5:53:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Hospital] is completed
```

this is my hospital java class

```
package hospital.model;



import java.sql.*;

import dbconnector.DBConnect;

public class Hospital {

    public String insertHoapitalDet(String MOHcode, String Hos_name, String Hos_email, String Hos_managername,  String Hos_address, String Hos_phoneNumber )  
    {   
        String output = ""; 

        try   
        {    
            DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
            Connection con = null;
            con = db.connect();


            if (con == null)    
            {
                return "Error while connecting to the database for inserting.";
            } 

            // create a prepared statement    
            String query = " insert into hospital "
                        + "(`hospitalID`,`mohCode`,`hospitalName`,`emailAddress`,`managerName`,`address`,`telephoneNo`)"     
                        + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 

            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query); 


            // binding values   
            preparedStmt.setInt(1, 0);    
            preparedStmt.setString(2, MOHcode);    
            preparedStmt.setString(3, Hos_name);    
            preparedStmt.setString(4, Hos_email);
            preparedStmt.setString(5, Hos_managername); 
            preparedStmt.setString(6, Hos_address);
            preparedStmt.setString(7, Hos_phoneNumber);

            // execute the statement    
            preparedStmt.execute();    
            con.close();  

            output = "Inserted successfully"; 

          }
          catch (Exception e)   
          {    
              output = "Error while inserting the hospital details.";    
              System.err.println(e.getMessage());     
          }
        return output; 
    }


    public String readHospitalDetails()  {

        String output = ""; 


        try   
        {   
            DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
            Connection con = null;
            con = db.connect();


           if (con == null)   
           {
               return "Error while connecting to the database for reading.";  
           } 


           // Prepare the html table to be displayed    
           output = "<table border=\"1\"><tr>"
                    + "<th>MOH Code</th>"
                    + "<th>Hospital Name</th>"
                    + "<th>Email</th>"
                    + "<th>Manager name</th>"
                    + "<th>Address</th>"
                    + "<th>TelNo</th>"
                    + "<th>UPDATE</th>"
                    + "<th>REMOVE</th>"
                    + "</tr>"; 

           String query = "select * from hospital";    
           Statement stmt = con.createStatement();    
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); 


           // iterate through the rows in the result set   
           while (rs.next())    
           {    
                String hospitalID = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("hospitalID"));     
                String MohCode = rs.getString("mohCode");     
                String hosName = rs.getString("hospitalName");     
                String emailAdd = rs.getString("emailAddress");  
                String managerName = rs.getString("managerName"); 
                String address = rs.getString("address"); 
                String telNo = rs.getString("telephoneNo"); 

                // Add into the html table     
                output += "<tr><td>" + MohCode + "</td>";     
                output += "<td>" + hosName + "</td>";     
                output += "<td>" + emailAdd + "</td>";     
                output += "<td>" + managerName + "</td>"; 
                output += "<td>" + address + "</td>"; 
                output += "<td>" + telNo + "</td>"; 

                // buttons     
                output += "<td><input name=\"btnUpdate\" type=\"button\"        "
                        + "value=\"Update\" class=\"btn btn-secondary\"></td>"      
                        + "<td><form method=\"post\" action=\"hospital.jsp\">"      
                        + "<input name=\"btnRemove\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Remove\"      class=\"btn btn-danger\">"     
                        + "<input name=\"hospitalID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + hospitalID      + "\">" 
                        + "</form></td></tr>";    
                } 

                con.close(); 

               // Complete the html table    
               output += "</table>";  
            }   

            catch (Exception e)   
            {    
                output = "Error while reading the hospital details.";    
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());   
            } 

            return output;   
    }

    public String updateHospitalDet(String ID, String MOHcode, String Hos_name, String Hos_email, String Hos_managername,  String Hos_address, String Hos_phoneNumber)  
    {   
        String output = ""; 

        try {   

            DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
            Connection con = null;
            con = db.connect(); 

        if (con == null)    
        {
            return "Error while connecting to the database for updating."; 
        } 

        // create a prepared statement    
        String query = "UPDATE hospital SET mohCode=?,hospitalName=?,emailAddress=?,managerName=?,address=?,telephoneNo=?      WHERE hospitalID=?"; 

        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query); 

        // binding values    
        preparedStmt.setString(1, MOHcode);    
        preparedStmt.setString(2, Hos_name);    
        preparedStmt.setString(3, Hos_email);   
        preparedStmt.setString(4, Hos_managername);
        preparedStmt.setString(5, Hos_address); 
        preparedStmt.setString(6, Hos_phoneNumber); 
        preparedStmt.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(ID)); 

        // execute the statement    
        preparedStmt.execute();    
        con.close(); 

        output = "Updated successfully";   

        }   
        catch (Exception e)  
        {    
            output = "Error while updating the hospital details.";    
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());     
        } 

        return output;  

    } 


    public String deleteHospitalDet(String hospitalID) 
    {   
        String output = ""; 

        try   
        {    
            DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
            Connection con = null;
            con = db.connect();  

        if (con == null)    
        {
            return "Error while connecting to the database for deleting.";
        } 

            // create a prepared statement    
            String query = "delete from hospital where hospitalID=?"; 

            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query); 

            // binding values    
            preparedStmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(hospitalID)); 

            // execute the statement    
            preparedStmt.execute();    
            con.close(); 

            output = "Deleted successfully";   
        }   
        catch (Exception e)   
        {    
            output = "Error while deleting the hospital details.";    
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());   
        } 

        return output;  

    }   
}
```

This is my HospitalService Class

```
package hospital.service;

import hospital.model.Hospital; 

//For REST Service 
import javax.ws.rs.*; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 

//For JSON 
import com.google.gson.*; 

//For XML 
import org.jsoup.*; 
import org.jsoup.parser.*; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

@Path("/Hospitals") 
public class HospitalService {


    Hospital hosObj = new Hospital();


    @GET  
    @Path("/")  
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML) 
    public String ReadHospitals() {

        return hosObj.readHospitalDetails(); 

    }


    @POST 
    @Path("/") 
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) 
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
    public String insertHoapitalDet(
            @FormParam("mohCode") String mohCode,       
            @FormParam("hospitalName") String hospitalName,    
            @FormParam("emailAddress") String emailAddress,       
            @FormParam("managerName") String managerName,
            @FormParam("address") String address,
            @FormParam("telephoneNo") String telephoneNo)
    {  
        String output = hosObj.insertHoapitalDet(mohCode, hospitalName, emailAddress, managerName,address,telephoneNo);  
        return output; 

    } 


    @PUT 
    @Path("/") 
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
    public String updateHospitalDet(String hospitalData) 
    {  
        //Convert the input string to a JSON object  
        JsonObject hospitalObject = new JsonParser().parse(hospitalData).getAsJsonObject(); 

        //Read the values from the JSON object  
        String hospitalID = hospitalObject.get("hospitalID").getAsString(); 
        String mohCode = hospitalObject.get("mohCode").getAsString();  
        String hospitalName = hospitalObject.get("hospitalName").getAsString(); 
        String emailAddress = hospitalObject.get("emailAddress").getAsString();  
        String managerName = hospitalObject.get("managerName").getAsString();
        String address = hospitalObject.get("address").getAsString();
        String telephoneNo = hospitalObject.get("telephoneNo").getAsString();

        String output = hosObj.updateHospitalDet(hospitalID, mohCode, hospitalName, emailAddress, managerName,address,telephoneNo); 

        return output; 

    } 

    @DELETE 
    @Path("/") 
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 

    public String deleteHospitalDet(String hospitalData) 
    {  
        //Convert the input string to an XML doc  
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(hospitalData, "", Parser.xmlParser());     

        //Read the value from the element <hospitalID>  
        String hospitalID = doc.select("hospitalID").text(); 

        String output = hosObj.deleteHospitalDet(hospitalID); 

        return output;  
    } 
}
```

I hope to reply if someone has fixed it.

Comment: Could you share the resources class, I mean the class or file where you defined the URLs

Comment: Could you share a structure resembling HospitalService if not the original class. I think its always better to share a structure similar to what you are trying to do. if its  your own personal things it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I did not understand what you meant by integrated with github.

I think this problem is due to the definition of `@Path("/")` in your methods, I am saying this assuming that you already have a class level annotation `@Path("/yourPathSpecificToThisClass")`. Then you may add `@Path("/somepath")` but not `@Path("/")`. 
This is because it only needs the request method(@Get, @Post etc) to identify the path.

=========================EDIT==============================

I will try and write a sample `HospitalService` class how I expect it to look,

```
//someAnnotations
@Path("/hospital")
public class HospitalService{


   @Get
   //@Path("/") if you have this annotation here remove it.
   public ResponseEntity readHospitals(/*take input*/) {
       //implementation
   }
   @Post
   //@Path("/") if you have this annotation here remove it.
   public ResponseEntity insertHoapitalDet(/*take input*/) {
       //implementation
   }
   @Put
   //@Path("/") if you have this annotation here remove it.
   public ResponseEntity updateHospitalDet(/*take input*/) {
       //implementation
   }
   @Delete
   //@Path("/") if you have this annotation here remove it.
   public ResponseEntity deleteHospitalDet(/*take input*/) {
       //implementation
   }


}
```

Hope you can figure it out now

Comment: my path like this. http://localhost:8080/Hospital/HospitalService/Hospitals   .my request methods including the **HospitalService.java** class.

Comment: If you can post a sample class that closely defines the original class you are working with, I may be able to explain it better based on that

Comment: And integrated means collaborate using Github. my single part is working and access resources.but when I clone the project, it gives pom.xml 1st line error.

Comment: I think you are talking about two entirely different things here.
one is an error in pom file which I think is due to some weird bug in eclipse(I guess you are using that) and other one is an error while running the application and that is the log you posted in your question

Comment: yes, .i m using eclipse. but pom.xml issue only comes when collaborate the project.is running issue not dependent pom.xml error

Comment: I am not sure about the pom error, but regarding the error log, I think its due to the reason I mentioned here

Comment: I edited my answer and added an example of what I am trying to explain via words

Comment: I implemented my HospitalService class similar like your format.i added class with my question

Comment: It will work if you remove`@Path("/") ` annotation from all method in `HospitalService` as mentioned in my answer. It will work. Hope you will figure out our